# The number of solutions of linear equations.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that $ n $ and $ k $ to be non-negative integers with $ k < n $.

Let $S(\{0,1 \})$ the number of integer solutions $ y = (y_1, \dotsc, y_{n-1 + k}) $ with $ y_j \in \{1,0 \}$ and $ j = 1,\dotsc, n -1 + k $ of the equation
$$
y_1+\dotso+y_{n+k-1}=k.
$$
Let $ S (\mathbb{N}) $ the number of integer solutions $ x = (x_1, \dotsc, x_{n}) $ with $ x_i \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ i = 1,\dotsc, n $ of the equation
$$
x_1+\dotso+x_n=k.
$$
Prove that $ S (\mathbb{N})=S(\{0,1 \}) $.

Edited 1. There is the "algorithm" with bars and stars (see eg [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)) that "proves" this equality. But the purpose of this question is simply to give a rigorous mathematical justification for this algorithm.

Edited 2. I am interested in a demonstration of the level set theory. I would be satisfied with an explicit bijection between $ S (\mathbb{N})$ and $S(\{0,1 \}) $.

Comment: A demonstration at the level of set theory? Do you know that it took Russell and Whitehead 586 pages to produce a demonstration of $1+1=2$ at the level of set theory?

Comment: I would be satisfied with an explicit bijection between $ S (\mathbb{N})$ and $S(\{0,1 \}) $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $y_1+\dotso+y_{n+k-1}=k$ there must be $k$ ones and $n-1$ zeros. Treat the ones as stars and the zeros as bars (see [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)). Then the $n-1$ bars form $n$ compartments of stars, and the counts of the stars in the compartments correspond to the numbers $x_i$.